# ORA-00918 Column ambiguously defined

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 SELECT INDIVIDUAL.INV_FNAME,
INDIVIDUAL.INV_LNAME,
INDIVIDUAL.INV_IC_NUM,
CUSTOMER.MEMBER_LEVEL,
CUSTOMER.MEMBER_POINT_BALANCE,
CUSTOMER.MEMBER_DISCOUNT_RATE,
PROGRAM_USER.USER_CONTACT_NUM,
PROGRAM_USER.USER_ADDRESS,
PROGRAM_USER.USER_CITY,
PROGRAM_USER.USER_STATE,
PROGRAM_USER.USER_ZIP_CODE,
PROGRAM_USER.USER_COUNTRY,
PROGRAM_USER.USER_EMAIL 
FROM PROGRAM_USER,CUSTOMER,INDIVIDUAL 
WHERE USER_ID = ‘san’;
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i think USER_ID column is there is multiple table. use appropriate tablename.USERID

Comment: Your joins are ill defined, you'll likely end up with a cartesian product. You need to tell the relations between `program_user`, `customer` and `individual`. You should use the keyword `join` syntax. As for the error, @Sachu is right, `user_id` is present in more than 1 table, so you should say which one you mean

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your query only USER_ID column in the where condition is not specified with a table name. I guess USER_ID is there in multiple table. Try the where condition with proper table name

```
SELECT INDIVIDUAL.INV_FNAME,
INDIVIDUAL.INV_LNAME,
INDIVIDUAL.INV_IC_NUM,
CUSTOMER.MEMBER_LEVEL,
CUSTOMER.MEMBER_POINT_BALANCE,
CUSTOMER.MEMBER_DISCOUNT_RATE,
PROGRAM_USER.USER_CONTACT_NUM,
PROGRAM_USER.USER_ADDRESS,
PROGRAM_USER.USER_CITY,
PROGRAM_USER.USER_STATE,
PROGRAM_USER.USER_ZIP_CODE,
PROGRAM_USER.USER_COUNTRY,
PROGRAM_USER.USER_EMAIL 
FROM PROGRAM_USER,CUSTOMER,INDIVIDUAL 
WHERE PROGRAM_USER.USER_ID = ‘san’;
```

Also like @HoneyBadger comment you need to specify the join between the tables

Comment: @cyrus u r welcome bro..but make sure you define the join between the tables

Comment: @downvoter can u pls tell why?